# Is it possible to use the Google Apps API to send a message content via POST to a PHP page elsewhere?

Tags: php, gmail, google-apps

Is it possible to create a gmail gadget with a button that would send a message's sender, subject, date and content via POST to some PHP page?

If so, any clues as to how this could be done?

I have been asked to integrate this as part of a small CRM, not sure if it can be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Contextual Gadgets](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/gadgets/contextual/) might cover what you need, alternatively you could fetch the messages externally using the [Mail feeds](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/docs/inbox_feed.html).

In either case, you will need to be authorised either via the Google Apps Marketplace or directly from the domain administrator by setting up OAuth credentials.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work. `Detects contextual clues in email, determines which types of content will trigger the gadget, and passes the triggering content to the gadget. An extractor does this by comparing a given regular expression to content in one or more given parts of each individual email message (From:, To:, etc.).`

Comment: Mail feeds are probably the best alternative.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's highly unlikely; the emails are considered private, no gadget should have access to them.